# Order custom posts by a date metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom metabox, where I store the date in plain text like this: `dd/mm/yy`and now I need to order the posts by that date.The custom field is called `event_informations_date`

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Event','posts_per_page' => 1000 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, save the date as a timestamp. then you can do the following in your `WP_Query`

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
           array ( 
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
              'meta_key'=> ' event_informations_date'
           )
         );
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add

```
meta_key => 'event_informations_date',
orderby => 'meta_value',
order => 'DESC'
```

However, because you are storing as plain text you will get a lexicographic ordering not a chronological ordering.  So for example, you'll get

23/01/2012
22/02/2012
15/12/2011
10/05/2013

which is a random date order.  I'm not sure whether you can overcome that unless you store the date as YYYY-MM-DD which lexicographically sorts in date order.

Answer (score 0):

### The solution is to order by meta_value_number

```
meta_key => 'event_informations_date',
orderby => 'meta_value_number',
order => 'DESC'
```